# As a US citizen, can I stay in South Korea past the expiration of my student visa, using the 90 days that I'm normally allowed to stay visa-free?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, south-korea, east-asia

I am a US citizen with a US passport. I will be studying abroad in Seoul later in the year and I am required to apply for a D-2 student visa for my program. My study abroad program will last for around 4 months, however I was planning on going to Korea a month earlier than the start of my program and staying for another month or two after it ends.

1. Will I need to apply for a separate visa for that?
2. I know that Korea allows visitors to stay 90 days without a visa so if the total amount of days I stay before and after my trip is less than 90 days will it be okay?
3. Is it possible for me to use that same D-2 visa to cover the extent of my trip or will it only cover the days of my program?
4. Lastly, am I able to regain entry into the country if I were to take trips outside of Korea during my time there?  I wanted to plan some side trips since the price of flying from country to country within Asia is so much cheaper than if I were to fly from the US.

Comment: A lot of countries don't like it when people who have student visas try to enter early or stay late, as this could indicate intentions to immigrate illegally. You would be well advised to plan your trips so that you avoid this perception.

Comment: @pnuts for what it's worth, the only answer on the question you linked is completely worthless (and the question is the opposite case of the one being asked here, so I'm not sure even a correct/helpful answer would help the OP here)

Comment: Actually, I asked on meta where my question was appropriate, and the response I got was that it would be ok either here or on expats (which I think applies to the OP too)